# Importing a file .py from a folder

Tags: python

I have a little problem.

Here is my structure :

Projet_a_remplir :

```
ode :

    ODESolvers.py

    util.py

    __init__.py

draw :

    DrawTools.py

    Shapes.py

    __init__.py

demo_project.py
```

In `demo_project.py`, I want to import `util` and `DrawTools`

So I wrote in `demo_project.py`: `from draw import DrawTools`, but i have this error : "ImportError: No module named 'DrawTools'".

I also tried :

```
import sys

sys.path.append("C:\\Users\\Ayyoub\\Desktop\\Développement logiciel\\Projet_a_remplir\\draw")

from DrawTools import *
```

Still the same error..

Could you help me with this ?

Comment: What do you mean? Are you get an error?

Comment: Yes my Error is : "ImportError: No module named Drawtools .. "

Comment: I Have edited the post on the 27 and it still not open .. I would like it to be open again, I still did not have an answer .. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Import is case sensitive. Change `from draw import Drawtools` to `from draw import DrawTools`.

Comment: Already did that, that's not the error, I modified my post .. sorry I am new in the forum, still confused ..

Answer (score 0):

You need to add in each subfolder `ode` and `draw` an (empty) file called `__init__.py`.

> The `__init__.py` files are required to make Python treat the
>   directories as containing packages; this is done to prevent
>   directories with a common name, such as string, from unintentionally
>   hiding valid modules that occur later (deeper) on the module search
>   path. In the simplest case, `__init__.py` can just be an empty file, but
>   it can also execute initialization code for the package or set the
>   `__all__` variable, described later.

Also see the documentation on [packages](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

Comment: I have already added  __init__.py in both files ( Sorry, I forgot to precise it ). 
But I still have the same problem. 
"ImportError: No module named Drawtools .. "

Comment: What do you mean, you added `__init__.py` to both  **files**. You mean **subdirectories**, right? In any case, update the structure of your project in your question, this is quite crucial information. Also add the exact error message you are getting.

Comment: I'm still looking for an answer if possible ..